# Overwrite input text field value of same element before posting to server

Tags: jquery

My input text field value has below
'Category A'

```
 <input type="text" id="ava" style="font-size:18px;" maxlength="25" placeholder="Your category" value="Category A"/>
```

Lets say user entered 'Category A'
How can we remove string 'Category' from above field value?

I tried below before posting the data to server via ajax call, this doesn't assign 'A' to my ava element work -

```
  $('#ava').val($("#ava").text().replace('Category',''));
```

Is this possible to be done to overwrite the ava field this way or should I use new variable to assign replaced element and assign back to ava ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a new variable is much better.

Also use a variable for `$('#ava')` like `var ava = $('#ava')` , it's not efficient to call same jQuery selector more than once.

This could be handy for working with strings in JS: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp

Answer (score 0):

you have to use val() not text()

```js
$('#ava').val($("#ava").val().replace('Category',''));
```